# How to obtain MAC address of WiFi network interface?

Tags: java, android, linux, macos, networking

It seems the java.net.NetworkInterface implementation of android does not have a
byte[]  getHardwareAddress() method
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html

I've found several forums of people trying to do this with no definitive answer, I need to get a somewhat cross-device UUID, so I can't rely on phone numbers or in ANDROID_ID (which can be overwritten and which I think depends on the user having a google account)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID

In linux you can use ifconfig or read from /proc/net/arp and you can easily get the Hardware address.

Is there a file in android that I can read?

There has to be a way to get this address since it's shown in the "Settings > About Phone > Status" of the phone.

Comment: I posted here working solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47789324/5330408

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> There has to be a way to get this
>   address since it's shown in the
>   "Settings > About Phone > Status" of
>   the phone.

Which means, if nothing else, you can go putter around the Android open source code, perhaps using Google Code Search, to figure out where it pulls that from.

Doing a bit of puttering myself, it would appear it is using `getMacAddress()` from `WifiInfo`.

Comment: That code can be found here
https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/wifi/AdvancedWifiSettings.java#L253-L265

Answer (score 96):

Late answer, but it can help others with the same "problem".

The [answer](http://wkjeldsen.dk/2010/index.php?a=17) is really straight forward:

```
WifiManager wifiMan = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(
                Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInf = wifiMan.getConnectionInfo();
String macAddr = wifiInf.getMacAddress();
```

The above code will get you the MAC address of your device, remember to have wifi enabled when grabbing the address. This code snippet should be used in your Activity.

Comment: just to add some detail, you will have to add an appropriate permission to androidManifest.xml to get it to work: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

Comment: Not necesary to have wifi enabled to get MAC address. I get it with wifi off.

Answer (score 11):

**UPDATE:**
Beginning **Android 6.0**,  above API will give you constant MAC address for all the devices, which is **02:00:00:00:00:00**. Refer below for details
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html
 Found another post that claims to find MAC address in 6.0, not tested it though
[How to get Wi-Fi Mac address in Android Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103798/how-to-get-wi-fi-mac-address-in-android-marshmallow)

Comment: I used solution to get my own mac address from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103798/how-to-get-wi-fi-mac-address-in-android-marshmallow on physical mobiles with Android 6, 7 and 8 and it works

Answer (score 2):

On Android Q, there is no way to access mac address anymore.

`WifiInfo.getMacAddress()` will always return `02:00:00:00:00:00`.

And `WifiConfiguration.getRandomizedMacAddress()` will not available anymore.

Comment: Solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103798/how-to-get-wi-fi-mac-address-in-android-marshmallow to get my own mac address works for me on an Android 10 emulator

Answer (score 1):

this my code and work well in android 5 +.

```
public static String getMacAddress() {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface nif : all) {
            if (!nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) continue;

            byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
            if (macBytes == null) {
                return "";
            }
            StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b : macBytes) {
                // res1.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF) + ":");
                res1.append(String.format("%02X:",b));
            }
            if (res1.length() > 0) {
                res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
            }
            return res1.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //handle exception
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/35830358/2826147

Answer (score 0):

Add Following Permission.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

WifiManager initialize in onCreate.

```
 WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getContext().getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

Use following function.

```
 public void WI-FI_MAC() {
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
    String macAddress = wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
    }
```

Comment: This returns the same address as the adapter's (`02:00:00:00:00:00`)

Comment: It's a restriction introduced in Android 6.0