# Jstring comparison in.c language

Tags: c, java-native-interface

How to compare two jstrings in c language.I am working with java native interface in which i am calling c native functions by java language the logic inside the c code is to compare the names for matching.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use java's `equals()` (or whatever you want) via `CallBooleanMethod()`:

```
jstring jstr1;
jstring jstr2;

jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, jstr1);
jmethodID mID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "equals", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");
jboolean equals = (*env)->CallBooleanMethod(env, jstr1, mID, jstr2);
```

This is a rough version of such comparison.

Comment: But after executing this code it shows the following error "expression must have pointer type".

Comment: As I said - it is rough. Show whole compiler message and what line exactly it can't understand? Is it compiled as C or C++ ?

Comment: Actually we have written the code in windows visual studio.we have created dll in which we added .c file in which our logic is present.