# jstring comparison in .c language what to do

Tags: c, java-native-interface

How to compare two jstrings in c language.I need this for jni execution in Which the logic is written in .c file for comparing two names

Comment: are you friend with Sai Prakash?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38204771/2173917

Answer (score 7):

** EDIT **

per @JonasVautherin comment:

While not causing a bug, this is one of the rare cases where use of `strncmp` *can* be replaced with `strcmp` without fear of reading out of bounds of the string.

The reason for that is native strings fetched from jvm are valid null terminated strings so no overflow will occur in this case, which is what `strncmp` guarantees.

This is also the reason why `strncmp` in this case will not cause a bug - it will terminate on \0 on either strings, or until the number of characters read is reached (reference: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/)

If you want to use pure native:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ClassName_MethodName(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring javaString1, jstring javaString2)   
{
   const char *nativeString1 = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, javaString1, 0);
   const char *nativeString2 = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, javaString2, 0);

   /* Now you can compare nativeString1 with nativeString2*/
   int res = strncmp(nativeString1, nativeString2, strlen(nativeString1);
   
   /* And don't forget to release the handles */

   (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, javaString1, nativeString1);
   (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, javaString2, nativeString2);
}
```

If you want to use Java from native code (same answer as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204771/jstring-comparision-in-c-language) all credit goes to the original author):

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ClassName_MethodName(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring javaString1, jstring javaString2)   
{
    /* Get java class String handle */
    jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, javaString1);
    /* Get method ID equals from String handle */
    jmethodID mID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "equals", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");
    /* Compare both methods, store in jboolean which can be case to uint8_t or bool if you're using C99*/
    jboolean equals = (*env)->CallBooleanMethod(env, javaString1, mID, javaString2);
}
```

Comment: With strncmp, what happens if nativeString1 is longer than nativeString2? Won't that overflow? Why not using strcmp instead?

Comment: This is still valid in 2022 who wouldve thought (:
I updated the answer per your comment, in general you are correct - you can replace `strncmp` with `strcmp` in this case, but it will not fail if you don't

Comment: There is a typo in your first sentence, that says `strcmp` twice (I guess the second should be `strncmp`?). Thanks for the answer :-)