# Can one programmatically obtain the MAC address of a device running Android 6.0+?

Tags: android, mac-address

Can one programmatically obtain the MAC address of a device running Android 6.0+?

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id),

> To provide users with greater data protection, starting in this
>   release, Android removes programmatic access to the device’s local
>   hardware identifier for apps using the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth APIs. The
>   WifiInfo.getMacAddress() and the BluetoothAdapter.getAddress() methods
>   now return a constant value of 02:00:00:00:00:00.

Does that mean it's impossible to get the device's MAC address in Android 6.0+? If it's possible, can you tell me how to do it in Android Studio?

Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11705949) only applies to devices with versions of Android below 6.0

Comment: stop adding android studio tag. Your question has nothing to do with android studio

Comment: @TimCastelijns Please stop editing my question. I want to use Android Studio.

Comment: that is great but that is totally irrelevant. Your question also applies to people using eclipse. Is your question about the IDE? No? Dont use the tag

Comment: Hi Dake. I agree with @TimCastelijns. Your question is regarding the Android APIs and not related to the IDE.

Comment: I posted here working solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47789324/5330408

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use an alternative way to get the MAC addr on a Android 6.0 device.

First add Internet User-Permission to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Secondly,

```
try {
        // get all the interfaces
        List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        //find network interface wlan0  
        for (NetworkInterface networkInterface : all) {
            if (!networkInterface.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) continue;
        //get the hardware address (MAC) of the interface    
            byte[] macBytes = networkInterface.getHardwareAddress();
            if (macBytes == null) {
                return "";
            }


            StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b : macBytes) {
                //gets the last byte of b
                res1.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF) + ":");
            }

            if (res1.length() > 0) {
                res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
            }
            return res1.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Can you please comment what your code does step by step? I'm a new programmer. :)

Comment: Edited. Hope this help :)

Comment: Can we modify the device's MAC address using your code? I guess I should ask another question for this.

Comment: I don't think you can change the MAC address. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address)

Comment: There are many apps that can modify the MAC address such as this one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wireless.macchanger

Comment: But, nevermind. Thanks for your answer. I might ask another question for this.

Comment: Hello again. In which function should I put your code? `protected void onCreate`?

Comment: or `public void onStart()`?

Comment: It depends on you. You can put these code in a function, and call it when you need.

Comment: Can you please explain your code even more? (+1) Also, the difference between `macBytes` and `res1`.

Comment: I'd like some more explanation.