# "Cannot return a value with void result type" error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The following code comes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38301932/6542063) answer

```
try {
        // get all the interfaces
        List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        //find network interface wlan0  
        for (NetworkInterface networkInterface : all) {
            if (!networkInterface.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) continue;
        //get the hardware address (MAC) of the interface    
            byte[] macBytes = networkInterface.getHardwareAddress();
            if (macBytes == null) {
                return "";
            }


            StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b : macBytes) {
                //gets the last byte of b
                res1.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF) + ":");
            }

            if (res1.length() > 0) {
                res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
            }
            return res1.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get error `Cannot return a value with void result type` on those 2 lines: `return "";` and `return res1.toString();` I put the code inside `public void onStart()` How do I fix this, and can you tell me the cause of this problem?

Comment: well what happens if the try block throws an exception? where is the return for that?

Comment: My guess is, you have that code inside a void method, and void methods don't return anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the line

```
public void onStart()
```

To

```
public String onStart()
```

This is because you are returning a String, whereas a void function does not return any data.

If the method cannot be changed to a String return type then you could just put the string into a variable that you declare earlier in the program and then use

```
return;
```

To exit the method.

Comment: Nope, you can't, cause it's a lifecycle method of Android activity which is overridden.

Comment: Thanks! I have a related problem. When I do the following. `macText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MACaddress);
                    macText.setText(macBytes);` I get `error: no suitable method found for setText(byte[])` How can I fix this?

Comment: You should create a new question for that. As it is unrelated to this question. I can answer it there.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning an empty String, just `return;`

Methods that are void do not return anything but you can use return statement to terminate an operation if some condition is not met!

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I have a related problem. When I do the following. `macText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MACaddress);
                    macText.setText(macBytes);` I get `error: no suitable method found for setText(byte[])` How can I fix this?

Comment: setText(String value) takes a String, not byte[] array. Just pass a String

Comment: What do you mean? How do we do that?

Comment: Here is what I mean https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html; there are methods to set text on TextView components - setText(int resId), setText(char[] text, int start, int len) , setText(CharSequence text, TextView.BufferType type), setText(CharSequence text)

Comment: I want to display `macBytes` to the user.How do I display it?

Comment: i don't see an option for my case. do you have an idea?

Comment: I am not sure you can show bytes using a TextView; unfortunately, you will have to find another way because I don't know

Comment: You have to build a `String` for the `setText()` method. Since you have a byte array, you will have to handle text encoding to do that correctly. Anyway, it's a very fundamental rule in Java that type assignment must be compatible; `byte[]` is not compatible with `String` by any standard conversion. You'll have to write your own.

Also, separate questions should be asked separately.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is clear, you are returning a value for a function public void onStart(). You are declaring the return type as void and yet you have return statements.

Try different ways to return the value, like put it in request/session or static variable(not recommanded) etc