# How to get mac address and ip in Nativescript?

Tags: android, typescript, nativescript

I want to get IP address from my mobile Android.

```
var context = application.android.context;
var wifiMgr = context.getSystemService("wifi");
var wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
var ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
console.log('ip', ip)
```

The result is: `JS: ip -2029999936`

But in fact this is not my IP.

Can you ask me any idea?

Update:

I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852900/get-mac-address-and-ip-in-nativescript) . I have this code:

Step1. In my component add this code:

```
import app = require("application");
app.android.context;
      constructor() {
      var context = android.content.Context;
      var wifiManager = app.android.context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      var wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
      var mac = wInfo.getMacAddress();
        }
```

Step2.
In AndroidManifest.xml add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

> Error: [ts] Cannot find name 'android'. [2304] in this line:      var
>   context = android.content.Context;
>   error TS1202: Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.

Comment: Please check this q&a [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852900/get-mac-address-and-ip-in-nativescript)

Comment: As this question isn't about Angular but NativeScript, I am removing the Angular tag. Good luck with your question !

Comment: Might your IP be: 248.255.87.64?

Comment: @Ved_Code_it I update post. Can you see again please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get mac address and ip in Nativescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852900/get-mac-address-and-ip-in-nativescript)

Comment: @Gourav read the question in first. I have another error, and I follow this `Possible duplicate of Get mac address and ip in Nativescript that you say`

Comment: `Cannot find name 'android` will be resolved with tns-platform-declarations https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-platform-declarations

Answer (score 1):

You should have `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` for capturing IP address.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Then all you have to is,

```
import * as application from 'tns-core-modules/application';
declare var android;

const wifiManager = application.android.context.getSystemService(android.content.Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
const connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
const ip = android.text.format.Formatter.formatIpAddress(connectionInfo.getIpAddress());
```

`declare var android;` is to avoid TS errors while access native apis. An alternative is to install `tns-platform-declarations` plugin and point the declaration files in your `references.d.ts`.

[Regarding the Mac Address, since Android 6.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes#behavior-hardware-id)

> To provide users with greater data protection, starting in this release, Android removes programmatic access to the device’s local hardware identifier for apps using the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth APIs. The WifiInfo.getMacAddress() and the BluetoothAdapter.getAddress() methods now return a constant value of 02:00:00:00:00:00.

So it doesn't seem officially supported.