# Get Mac Adress on Android

Tags: nativescript

How i can get *mac address* by using **nativescript** for android device?

I tried get mac like at this question [Get mac address and ip in Nativescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852900/get-mac-address-and-ip-in-nativescript)

Also, i tried:

```
let mac = java.net.NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress();
```

And i get error

```
TypeError: test.getHardwareAddress is not a function
```

But, if i print `console.log(java.net.NetworkInterface)` at the log we will see `getHardwareAddress`

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Manoj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54517045/how-to-get-mac-address-and-ip-in-nativescript?rq=1) worked for me, but since Android 6.0:

> To provide users with greater data protection, starting in this release, Android removes programmatic access to the device’s local hardware identifier for apps using the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth APIs. The WifiInfo.getMacAddress() and the BluetoothAdapter.getAddress() methods now return a constant value of 02:00:00:00:00:00.