# How do mobile apps get the phone's MAC address in Android Q？

Tags: android, mac-address, android-10.0

In [Official site](https://developer.android.com), we can see this:

> Devices running on Android Q transmit randomized MAC addresses by
>   default. If your app handles an enterprise use case, the platform
>   provides several new APIs: Obtain randomized MAC address: Device owner
>   apps and profile owner apps can retrieve the randomized MAC address
>   assigned to a specific network by calling getRandomizedMacAddress().
>   Obtain actual, factory MAC address: Device owner apps can retrieve a
>   device's actual hardware MAC address by calling getWifiMacAddress().
>   This method is useful for tracking fleets of devices.

[More details](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/data-identifiers?hl=zh-cn#randomized-mac-addresses)

[Another Reference](https://source.android.google.cn/devices/tech/connect/wifi-mac-randomization)

I used [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705906/programmatically-getting-the-mac-of-an-android-device/44387673#44387673) to get MAC address in android Q, but I failed. I get randomised MAC address, but not real MAC address.
So How can I get phone's MAC address in my app?

Comment: Apparently, you need to write [a device policy controller app](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/device-management), and have it run in device owner mode. This requires specially provisioned devices and is not available to ordinary Android apps.