# How to get Mac address in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mac-address

I need to obtain the MAC address of my android device using Kotlin. I've searched online, but I haven't found anything useful. I am using WiFi MAC address as Unique id, How to get the actual MAC address of the Android device in Kotlin ?

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705906/programmatically-getting-the-mac-of-an-android-device

Comment: To convert Java code in Android studio use CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+K

Comment: See "[Best practices for unique identifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids)" to learn which identifiers are appropriate for your use case.  Note in particular that that page says: "[I]t's generally not recommended to use MAC address[es] for any form of user identification."  Can you explain why you need a "Unique ID" here?

Answer (score 5):

```
fun getMac(context: Context): String {
 val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
 val info = manager.connectionInfo
 return info.macAddress.toUpperCase()
}
```

your app must now have the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions.

default value if you don't have grant access is `02:00:00:00:00:00`