# getMacAddress() returns null in Android 11? How to get mac address for Android 11?

Tags: android, android-11

```
{
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface nif : all) {
            if (!nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) continue;

            byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
            if (macBytes == null) {
                macTestResultString = "";
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(App.TAG, EXCEPTION + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return macTestResultString;
}
```

Comment: Please read the changes in Android 11 https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#mac-11-plus Without root you wont be able to get the mac address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting mac address on device api more than 10 is almost impossible. Android's new security restriction no longer allow to access mac address [read here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#mac-11-plus).
Why do you need the mac address mention the reason might be there is some other solution that may help.

Comment: is there any way to get mac address even with security permissions?

Comment: For android version < 6 refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11705949/16441984. For android version >= 6 due to security reasons mac address can't be retrieved and will return constant value.